# Threading In a WinForm

Tags: multithreading, winforms

Everything in my app is working like I want but I don't really understand how exactly? I setup a couple of threads to monitor some resources the app will need from time to time.  The threads update a couple of labels saying "all good" or "uh oh"(not really but you get the idea).  I setup the test of InvokeRequired to make sure it executes on the thread that created the labels and everything works great.

What I don't understand is... If i'm typing into a a textbox while the labels are being updated shouldn't i see some kind of lag in my typing since it's on the same thread or at least have to implement some code so i can continue typing where i left off? My guess is that the Invoke method takes care of things so i can continue typeing where i left off.

It's working so I shouldn't complain but I don't want some bug to popup a month from now that I really don't understand.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Without seeing some code, this is impossible to answer definitively.  However, updating labels doesn't take long... it's probably happening in microseconds on your machine.

Comment: if I'm typing in textbox1 then label1 and label2 are updated how is my cursor getting back to place where i left off?  the textbox is no longer the active control once the labels update right?

Comment: Nope - rendering text in the labels does not require input focus.  You will be fine - just carry on coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is nothing to worry about.

Explanation: Pretty much every GUI system in existence, including WinForms, is single-threaded, so nothing happens simultaneously, but also consider that most operations are lightning quick too (even painting).

A better explanation would explain how the GUI message loop works, but I'm too lazy to explain it, but I will explain the part you say you don't understand. This is the sequence of events when you type into a textbox:

1. Keypress message received by the root window (by its message loop)
2. Keypress message is dispatched to the textbox from the root window
3. Keypress message received by textbox. Textbox updates its internal state by appending the new character to its internal `Value` string.
4. The textbox informs the parent window that the texbox needs to be repainted at the next nearest opportunity because its text value has changed.
5. The root window gets the next message: which is a request to perform a method invokation (because `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` was called from another thread).
6. The root window executes this invoke method.

   1. In this case, your `Invoke`'d code, as far as I can tell, just sets the `Text` property of a label, this operation is quick as it just sets the internal state of the label, it does not cause it to be painted directly, instead (as in step 4), it marks the label as "invalidated" and must be repainted at the next best opportunity (see step 8).
7. The root window gets the next message: a request to repaint the textbox
8. The root window instructs the textbox to repaint itself
9. The root window gets the next message, or sits idle waiting for the next message to be received

So yes, there *is* the possibility for lag or a delay in the message cycle, for example, if your `Invoke`'d code takes more than a few miliseconds to execute. If you add `Thread.Sleep(10*1000)` in your Invoke'd code, you'll see.

Comment: Thanks! that helps.  My concern is those updates taking control of the cursor which kind of defeats the purpose of threading.  The UI will just be receiving the results of the "work" so it will happen in a blink. For grins I think i may try updating some "user input" controls and see what happens.  Thanks again for the feedback